# Django: How to use an annotation from a parent queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have an `Item` class which can be annotated using a custom queryset `add_is_favorite_for` method:

```py
class ItemQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def add_is_favorite_for(self, user):
        """add a boolean to know if the item is favorited by the given user"""
        condition = Q(id__in=Item.objects.filter(favoriters=user).values("id"))
        return self.annotate(is_favorite=Condition(condition)) # True or False

class Item(Model):
    objects = Manager.from_queryset(ItemQuerySet)()
```

It works as expected. For example:

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> Item.objects.add_is_favorite_for(user) # each item has now a `is_favorite` field
```

Then, I added a `Factory` model and link `Item` model to it using a 1->N relationship:

```py
class Factory(Model):
    pass  # ...

class Item(Model):
    objects = Manager.from_queryset(ItemQuerySet)()
    advised_in = models.ForeignKey(
        Factory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="advised_items",
    )
```

Now, I'd like to be able to return a `Factory` QuerySet, whose `advised_items` fields will all contain the `is_favorite` annotation too.
I don't know how to do this, I saw no example of such a thing in the doc, maybe I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`Prefetch`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch):

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

Factory.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('advised_items', queryset=Item.objects.add_is_favorite_for(some_user))
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. I'm looking for to return a `Factory` queryset, not Item. Plus, testing your code returns a `TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s)`. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @DavidD.: sorry, it should have been `Factory`, so `Factory.objects...`

Comment: Thanks! However I still get the `TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): <django.db.models.query.Prefetch object at 0xffff9ce211b0>` error. I just checked that `Factory.objects.prefetch_related("advised_items")` worked and `Item.objects.add_is_favorite_for(user)` worked too

Comment: @DavidD.: can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: I added the whole traceback using the last solution you provided

Comment: @DavidD.: I made a typo, it is `.prefetch_related`, not `.annotate`.